# GetWindowLongPtr in D on Windows?

Tags: d

I was unable to find 'GetWindowLongPtr' in standard D's modules. So I went to MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx ).  Attached the lib:

```
pragma (lib, "user32.lib");
```

Declared a function:

```
extern (Windows)
{
    export LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtrA(in HWND hWnd, in int nIndex);
}
```

But the compiler (dmd) says: _GetWindowLongPtrA@8

This scheme worked for AppendMenu WinAPI call. WEhat I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know D, but I know that `GetWindowLongPtrA` is an x64 WinAPI function. Its equivalent 32-bit WinAPI function is [`GetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`GetWindowLongA`). Try using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetWindowLongPtrA` is only present in the 64-bit version of `user32.dll`. For 32 bits, it is a macro for `GetWindowLongA`.

For more comprehensive Windows bindings, you should check out the Windows bindings project:

http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/WindowsApi